# api v 3 google maps selecting cities

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hello is it possible to select custom address after geocoding?
Like in image below?

[image]

Also can look on this link from Google maps: [click here](http://mapy.google.pl/maps?q=Galesburg,%20IL,%20United%20States&hl=pl&ll=40.929596,-90.293198&spn=0.360544,0.837021&sll=40.497092,-89.697876&sspn=1.451549,3.348083&oq=galesbu&hnear=Galesburg,%20Hrabstwo%20Knox,%20Illinois,%20Stany%20Zjednoczone&t=m&z=11)

Comment: You have use geo-cordinates and zoom levels to go to the required addresses right?

Comment: No, I would like to select a region. F.e. when You searching in google maps for London it will be highlithed to borders of the city. You can check it in link I send below the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Twitter-API has a service that returns those polygon-boundaries.

[Add "Search Area" outline onto google maps result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706484/add-search-area-outline-onto-google-maps-result/9711958#9711958)

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not available directly in the Maps API. However, if you had the polygon boundaries of the region, you could create a polygon overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool to create the boundary by creating it and it will get converted into a JSON file... Use the coordinates of the JSON file to create the polygon....