# Google Maps V3 - How to retrieve zone (county, city, state, etc) polygons?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps currently highlights/delimits a searched-place area with a neat polygon.

In my wish, that could be accomplished by:
1st) Retrieving the place with `google.maps.Geocoder`, `geocoder` method;
2nd) Drawing the polygon-area using an array of `LatLngs` from `google.maps.GeocoderResult`;
But, There is no such data on the results;

Does V3 API, solely, provide that info? How can I use it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add "Search Area" outline onto google maps result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706484/add-search-area-outline-onto-google-maps-result)