# Google has started highlighting search areas in Pink color. Is this feature available in Google Maps API 3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Since Jan 2012, Google has started highlighting search areas in pick color. See the details here: 
http://googlesystem.blogspot.in/2012/01/highlight-areas-in-google-maps.html

Does anyone know if this can be programmatically done using google maps API 3? I would want to show my  cities in the map highlighted as shown in the link above.

I have already tried the Geocode API where I search for a city. That API only gives me the lat and long information. It does not help me in plotting the city boundaries.

Comment: If you go through the code of Google Map Maker you will find a file similar to this (http://www.google.com/mapmaker?f=q&hl=en&q=yordon+center&output=js&gw=30&ll=41.934943%2C-88.776348&spn=0.001453%2C0.006459&z=18&vpid=1394074375923). Just view the source of the file and somewhere in there is the polygon information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add "Search Area" outline onto google maps result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706484/add-search-area-outline-onto-google-maps-result)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No. It's not available in the API.

(It *may* be available in the future. Features of Google Maps do migrate into the API, **but** Google don't make announcements in advance and no-one has a crystal ball.)

You would need to find the city boundaries and draw the line yourself. Boundary data is almost certainly public-domain for the US. Other jurisdictions may not be so forthcoming.

Comment: Thanks! As of now I am plotting a polygon to highlight the boundaries.  When Google makes this feature available in API, it would be great!!

Comment: Has situation changed since this answer was posted?

Comment: @Sangharsh While it's true the API has changed out of all recognition in 3½ years, I don't think Google have made this easy, if it's now possible at all. But comments are not the place; ask another question (referencing all the other relevant questions you can find, including this one. The sidebar will help there).

Comment: While I haven't seen any option from Google to do this in their API, [I found a solution to get the boundries of administrative areas here. Hope this helps!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31865958/3084239)

Comment: This post is almost a year old now, any one know if feature been added to API yet? (Or any plans to do it)

Answer (score 2):

Although a very old post my answer might help somebody out there as am landing on this post every time I query for bounding box:

Yes we can get the bounding box coordinates that google is using to highlight a region using Googles geocoding service. check for the response of the API call in the below sample from Google.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple?refresh=1

Comment: No, geocoding only provide point lat long, no polygon outline provided

Comment: check the response of Gmap API you can see north east and south west coordinates.

Comment: Thanks, Mahesh! This was all I needed since I was just trying to get the city within view of the Map. It doesn't return a polygon, but at least it does the bounds!