# Google Maps API V3: How to get region border coordinates (polyline) data?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates, google-polyline

I'm trying to get (specified) region borders as GMaps coordinates (to form a polyline) from Google Maps. Is this possible in some way? (either from maps.google.com or my own GMaps in my own domain).

**Note:**
I know you can draw/outline regions manually with tools intended for it (like http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/v3tool.html), but covering a large region ACCURATELY is a ton of work.
The draw-it-yourself answer is not an option in this case.

### Example:

1. https://maps.google.com/ -> type in "Uusimaa, Finland"
2. You can see the pink-ish border that outlines the wanted region
3. That border is the polyline that I need the coordinates of

### Requirements:

- Extract the region data coordinates (if available) from a given search (as in the example)
- If the previous is not possible, a source to an ACCURATE map of the region "Uusimaa, Finland" is required (plain googling did not yield needed results).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is becoming a FAQ. See the replies to these questions:

[Add "Search Area" outline onto google maps result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706484/add-search-area-outline-onto-google-maps-result)

[Google has started highlighting search areas in Pink color. Is this feature available in Google Maps API 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207045/google-has-started-highlighting-search-areas-in-pink-color-is-this-feature-avai)

Comment: The short answer would be "No" then since the data cannot be extracted from a search result in any way, leaving only drawing the area boundaries manually. Thanks.

Comment: In one of the threads I linked to, someone said that they come from the Twitter API, but I haven't had the opportunity to confirm this.

Comment: To some extent, yes. With "Uusimaa" the bounding box does not even contain the full area that it covers, and even then I would need accurate, confirmable coordinates. (Without better knowledge) I'd say it outputs "rough sketch" of the area at best. Hard to say.

Comment: **Confirmed. You can get it from the Twitter API**, and you got me curious so I had to give it a try. Here's a quick and dirty demo: http://maps.forum.nu/v3/geocoding.html - When there are multiple results I am only taking the first one so it only works for big US cities with unique names. Try Chicago, New Orleans, Spokane, Detroit.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for finding it out. In my case it's unsuitable since I would need it to work with Uusimaa (or in Finland in general), but US residents should benefit from it.

Comment: @Marcelo your link is dead