# Dutch postal code boundaries in Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to put an overlay over de borders of a Dutch postal code.
Google Maps does this like a charm in their normal interface.
It puts a dashed border around the bounds of the postal code.

http://goo.gl/maps/fujSB

But the Google Maps Geocoding API only returns a right-upper and lef-under limit:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=3335,+NL&sensor=true

Has anybody got any clue on how to tackle this, so that we can put a polygon overlay over the exact borders of the Dutch postal code?
Any other services besides Google Maps are okay for us too, we've looked at others yet.

Kind regards,
Gerard Nijboer

Comment: Hi, I am sorry, have you found a solution to your task? Cause I am looking for the same thing, but for Italian post codes...

Answer (score 0):

See my reply to **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194046/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-get-region-border-coordinates-polyline-data/12194452)**.

Those borders seem to come from the Twitter API.

Look also at the comments where I posted a link to a quick demo.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo. I've seen your post before. I can't get the Twitter Geo API to work to get the bounds of the Dutch postal code `3335`. Hitting this query in Google Maps shows you what I want: http://goo.gl/maps/fujSB. Could you see whether and how to achieve something like that through the Twitter Geo API? Because I can't seem to find documentation on that.

Comment: Documentation is here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/geo/search - but unfortunately, the latest version of that API, (1.1), requires authentication, and it's a bit of a nightmare to figure out how to authenticate. It is not as simple as Google's API key. For that reason I am not spending time on putting together a better demo or experimenting further. I hope Twitter will simplify the process when they notice a sharp drop in usage.