# where can i download the lng and lat coordinates of Italy

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am building a interactive map (google map api) of Italy. I want to use polygons to show the regions and ech region has a different color (overlay). So on every region page the visitor get a nice overview where the region is.

Is there a site where i can download the lat/lon coordinates of the regions of Italy? I tried google but with no succes...

Thanks..remco

Comment: You can find the way to do it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194046/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-get-region-border-coordinates-polyline-data

Answer (score 0):

Check out this man,

http://www.mapsofworld.com/lat_long/italy-lat-long.html

it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the map (maps.google.com) and choose "What's here?", and you will get the coords

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting site if you are still looking, They contain polygons of virtually every country and other related data. HTH

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-0-boundary-lines/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Natural Earth Data set (which is available in FusionTables), a good source of country polygons and sub-region polygons is [gadm.org](http://www.gadm.org/)

KMZ can be displayed directly using the Google Maps API v3, but there are other formats available.