# all latitude and longitude to spacific regoin and compare it with the latitude and the longitude of the users

Tags: android, performance, google-maps, math

In my project android application the user can pin the location from the Google map then the the application give the latitude and the longitude to the location that is pined but the problem I want to know all the users inside this regoin (for example King Abdul Aziz university),the user and their latitude and the longitude is saved in the Database but
 first :how can I Know all latitude and the longitude in specific region from only point(latitude and the longitude) that is inside this region 
second: how  compare it with the latitude and the longitude of the users
can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps API doesn't allow you to get region borders as GMaps coordinates yet. See this article for more information: [Google Maps API V3: How to get region border coordinates (polyline) data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194046/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-get-region-border-coordinates-polyline-data).

To find out whether a given point lies inside, outside, or on the boundary of a region use one of [PIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) algorithms.