# How to draw boundary around the address based on latitude amd longitude in Google Map

Tags: google-maps

I have got a drop down of **State** and cities .
Upon selection of a State , corresponding cities will be displayed and once clicked on Go button , i am showning that particular city uisng Google Map.

Could you please let me know if how  is it posible to show that  area  around dashed or dotted lines ??

I see that Poly line doesn't suit my requirement as it draws only one line .

Right now i have got only latitude and longitude obtained via

```
$(document).on('click', '.gobtn', function(event) {
    $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address + '', function(data) {
        latitude_res = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        longitude_res = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    }).done(function() {
    });

});
```

This is my simple jsfiddle how i am showing map

http://jsfiddle.net/ZLuTg/1010/

Could you please let me know how to draw dashed / dotted  around the boundary of latitude amd longitude ??

How to draw boundary around the address based on  latitude amd longitude

Comment: why downvoted ?? any idea on how to do this ??

Answer (score 1):

If have a way to find the boundaries for the location you can use polyline to draw the border.  Just close the shape, by joining the first point back to the last point.

If you don't already have the boundaries, according to the answer to this  question [Google Maps API V3: How to get region border coordinates (polyline) data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194046/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-get-region-border-coordinates-polyline-data) and others, google maps will not provide the boundaries for you.