# How to highlite region of dropdown selected area on Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

How to highlight dropdown selected area region on google map, but I want this through jQuery or javascript, My actuall requirement is like this dropdown is autocomplete address and which area or city when I select on dropdown, Google Map just highlite those area by my custom highlite color.

```html
<select> 
   <option>Los angeles </option>
   <option>California</option>
   <option>New yourk</option>
</select>

<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d423284.5905135276!2d-118.41173249999996!3d34.020498899999986!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x80c2c75ddc27da13%3A0xe22fdf6f254608f4!2sLos+Angeles%2C+CA%2C+USA!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1442834158072" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to display location on user selection:

**Example**

```js
 var locations = [
        { City: 'New York', Location: '!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d193578.74109040972!2d-73.97968099999999!3d40.703312749999995!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b%3A0xc80b8f06e177fe62!2sNew+York%2C+Yhdysvallat!5e0!3m2!1sfi!2sfi!4v1442836316382' },
        { City: 'Los Angeles', Location: '!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d423284.5905135276!2d-118.41173249999996!3d34.020498899999986!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x80c2c75ddc27da13%3A0xe22fdf6f254608f4!2sLos+Angeles%2C+CA%2C+USA!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1442834158072' }
    ];

    var seloption = "";
    $.each(locations, function (i) {
        seloption += '<option value="' + locations[i].Location + '">' + locations[i].City + '</option>';
    });
    $('#optLocations').append(seloption);


    $('#optLocations').on('change', function () {
        var src = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=" + this.value;
        $('#embedMap').attr('src', src);

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="optLocations" >
        <option disabled selected> -- select a location -- </option>
</select>
<br/>
<iframe id="embedMap" width="600" src="about:blank" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen='true'></iframe>
```

**Example 2**

Using [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide)

```js
  var locations = [
        { City: 'New York' },
        { City: 'Los Angeles' },
        { City: 'Moscow' },
        { City: 'Paris' }
    ];

    var seloption = "";
    $.each(locations, function (i) {
        seloption += '<option value="' + locations[i].City + '">' + locations[i].City + '</option>';
    });
    $('#optLocations').append(seloption);


    $('#optLocations').on('change', function () {
        //the key is provided for demonstration purposes only! 
        var embedUrl = 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyB-MCwhB8ITpjZQyznpnJtPP0ca-62s-jw&q=' + this.value;
        $('#embedMap').attr('src', embedUrl);

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="optLocations" >
        <option disabled selected> -- select a location -- </option>
</select>
<br/>
<iframe id="embedMap" width="600" src="about:blank" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen='true'></iframe>
```

Comment: Please explain the code. Where do you get the `Location` value?

Comment: @AnhTriet, follow [Embed a map](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3544418?hl=en) page

Comment: It means that if we have 100 locations, we have to do `Embed map` 100 times to get the location data? :(

Comment: That's great! Thanks a lot! :D
For anyone who wants to know more about `Google Map Embed`, check this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start).

Comment: Your both examples woks for me, Thnx for this. Can you give me some more help? how to I highlight selected region by my own color like blue or other my own define color except pink i.e default highlight color.

Comment: can you know how to highlight region by blue color

Answer (score 0):

Currently, **you cannot do it** through Google Map API. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194046/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-get-region-border-coordinates-polyline-data) for more detail.

However, there is a workaround way mentioned in `Vadim Gremyachev` answer: using `Google Map Embed`.

If you want to highlight countries (not states), use `Geo Charts` service. Its documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart?csw=1#Regions).