# How to style boundaries around the country using jquery ui maps?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-map

How to style boundaries around the country region (for ex: in google maps 'France',coloring border around the country region).. I am using jquery-ui-maps v3.. How can I do this ?

Comment: by writing and then and sharing your code

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available yet.

I found this link : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207045/google-has-started-highlighting-search-areas-in-pink-color-is-this-feature-avai`

Hope it works for any other user. :)