# Let Google Map display the city border in europe?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Right now I'm working on a custom Google Map which shows waterstations in Brussels. Everything worked out well but now I got stuck.

If you type "Bruxelles Capitale" into Google Maps, you can see a red border along the city's border.

Is there a way (Javascript pre set?!) to display this by default? My Map is zoomed exactly onto Brussels.

Comment: this seems to be a common question. 

http://stackoverflow.com/q/9706484/616606  

http://stackoverflow.com/q/11207045/616606

Comment: Ok thanks. I've been searching for about 3h but couldn't find those questions. Thank you!