# Retrieve radius of given location?

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

Is there a way to retrieve the radius of a given location using the google API?

I want to use the above information so that when a user performs a search relevant to a location I can set the distance radius based on the size of the location instead of having a fixed radius on all searches.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps can show the perimeter of a geographic area. Nevertheless, it seems that Google has not enabled this functionality through the API.

[Google Maps API V3: How to get region border coordinates (polyline) data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194046/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-get-region-border-coordinates-polyline-data)

[Add "Search Area" outline onto google maps result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706484/add-search-area-outline-onto-google-maps-result)

[Google has started highlighting search areas in Pink color. Is this feature available in Google Maps API 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207045/google-has-started-highlighting-search-areas-in-pink-color-is-this-feature-avai)

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Places API response in the Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_responses) contains a [viewport](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceGeometry) which is:

```
viewport | LatLngBounds | The preferred viewport when displaying this Place on a map. This property will be null if the preferred viewport for the Place is not known.
```

That can be used to calculate a radius if that is what you need or directly as the area to search.