# draw boundary of searched region on google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my android app, i need to highlight searched region by drawing polygon.

How to draw polygon to highlight region/city/state just by keywords? how can I get all co-ordinates of boundaries to draw polygon?

i.e. same as housing android app. for any searched region, they are showing boundary on the google map, from where they are getting these data?.

Any sources to get these region boundary data as google api is available for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't  know about any service that gives you back the borders of a region, but you can build one yourself.

Have a look at this answer here: [Google Maps how to Show city or an Area outline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861822/google-maps-how-to-show-city-or-an-area-outline/31865958#31865958)
(it is not an Android specific answer, but it explains where to get the coordinates and it gives guidelines on how to parse them).

Best of luck!