# How can i mark different districts in Google Maps, using Location Based Services

Tags: android, service, location, maps

Good morgning people.

I have a new project i am working on and i want to know, is it possible to mark/color districts in Google Maps. Using Location Based Services i want to mark different cities or districts?

I would be very happy if you could tell me if its possible. I am doing some research and could not get any helpful answers.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes its possible. See the link [Marking Google Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861822/google-maps-how-to-show-city-or-an-area-outline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can add precisely if you got lat and long of location**

follow [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker) and its easy