# Maps API Places Details

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, maps

I'm trying to create a map which has already highlighted a place on the Map with in the top left corner the business name, address, reviews etc. If you go here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start

And under 'Highlight a place or an address' type the name of a local business, you will see what I mean.

However.. In the API docs I can't find a way to create this type of map! With the places API you can request the places' details, but I can't seem to find how to use those details to create a map like this in the javascript API. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "highlighted a place on the Map" is a Google Maps feature which is not available in the API. However, you can refer to this workaround for your need
[Google Maps how to Show city or an Area outline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861822/google-maps-how-to-show-city-or-an-area-outline/31865958#31865958)

Comment: Thanks Yong Boon Fei, I was already afraid of that, but thanks for taking the time to confirm! I'll have a look at your suggestion.