# How to Draw Area of Cities in the Country in Android

Tags: android, image, draw, country, city

What's the best way for Draw Area of Cities in any Country in Android. Each city separate the others via city line. So you can click and select any city, you want.

Any ideas?? If you give me any keyword, i can search with it.

Thanks a lot.

[I actually want to do something like that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zSSu.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31865958/5354875
Check this one. It seems like the same problem

Comment: ohh, really thanks. can i go without google map?