# How google get polygon data for locality in a city

Tags: google-maps, maps, openstreetmap

I have seen google showing polygon lines for locality in a map. eg: https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Koramangala,+Bengaluru,+Karnataka/@12.9354922,77.6146828,14z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x3bae144ed898fc2d:0x1681f38e8c00ae56!8m2!3d12.9279232!4d77.6271078

I wanted to know how google gets this data. Do they use any kind of mapping of images to the government data available in the countries in the world. I dont think all the countries provide data (lats, longs) at such granular level.

Answer (score 2):

Right now this feature is unavailable for Google Maps API. But there is a feature request on Google's Issue Tracker that you can star and comment on. 
Here's the link:
https://issuetracker.google.com/35816953

There are workarounds for this though where you get the data elsewhere and draw the polygons yourself.
Here's the link to that:
[Google Maps how to Show city or an Area outline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861822/google-maps-how-to-show-city-or-an-area-outline/31865958#31865958)