# Can Google or any maps API provide array of gps cords representing boundary of a district or a state

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps, openstreetmap

we have some GPS tagged data and we trying to analyze data to see if the data originated from some particular districts in India.

We were originally planing to use google maps api to see of the cords are in a district

but that means too many request .

Is there any way i could extract a gps cords list  which could show the boundaries of a physical area like a district or a city or a state from any maps API like googlemaps ,openstreetmaps or any other api  .So that we could check it mathematically if the point is inside or outside the area.

Comment: can some one tell me why this question was down voted ?

Comment: Google API currently don't provide this feature.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207045/google-has-started-highlighting-search-areas-in-pink-color-is-this-feature-avai

Answer (score 3):

OSM has [boundaries](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Boundaries).

You can download them for example by using [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Boundaries). Alternatively just use the service provided by wambacher where you can download specific boundaries from OSM: https://osm.wno-edv-service.de/boundaries/

Comment: thank you , i got the list  but i do't know why i was down voted for asking this question .