# How can I get outline of a city with a free shape on google maps api?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to shape cities with google maps api, like in the picture provided:
[image: google maps api with a shape for the city]

Do you know from where I can get these shapes for the cities? (I need for USA and Canada cities only.) All I can find are rectangular bounds of localities, which google provides.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add "Search Area" outline onto google maps result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706484/add-search-area-outline-onto-google-maps-result)

Comment: It doesn't look very similar on the pictures...

Answer (score 0):

You could create polygons and then save them in a database for recreation later on the map.

Comment: Yes I could, what I'm asking is if these polygons are available from somewhere and I can use them ready.