# how can I display a google region in my map?

Tags: google-maps

If I type "Sunshine Coast Regional, QLD" into google maps, I get a nice outline around the region as shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efhD5.png) link.

How can I get this same outline in my maps? Which service do I need to use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add "Search Area" outline onto google maps result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706484/add-search-area-outline-onto-google-maps-result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [feature request 109](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=109) in the public issue tracker.

It looks like Google is working on it. I can suggest starring the feature request to express your interest and receive further updates.