# Google Maps get city bounds and draw city polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am looking for a google maps api to get city bounds (latitude and longitude array) in order to draw a polygon container

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - see [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add "Search Area" outline onto google maps result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706484/add-search-area-outline-onto-google-maps-result)

Answer (score 0):

From what I searched, at this moment there is no option from Google in the Maps API v3.
You can use [Polygons creator](http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/index.py)