# Drawing region on google maps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

If I search a query in google maps for example "carlton victoria australia" then it will give me a map of the region with the border around that area.
[image: Carlton]

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to get list of all regions from the google map api for
   certain province or country?
2. Can I combine the region information for example, change the color and also add some infowindow on top of the region?
3. What kind of level of the region that I can get from the api (district, subdistrict, village)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will be glad to help you if you get stuck on a specific programming problem, but we are not here to read API documentation for you. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I have read the documentation and as far as I know I did not find what I need. Thus, I asked this question in stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Google Maps JavaScript API doesn't expose any boundaries of geographic features. There is very old feature request in the public issue tracker to add this functionality, however it looks like Google didn't set high priority on this:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35816953

Feel free to star the public feature request to express your interest and subscribe to further updates from Google.

You can get polygons from other sources and add them to Google maps as additional layers.

The nice workaround to get polygons in GeoJSON format from OpenStreetMap is described in the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40172098/5140781

So, if you download the GeoJSON you will be able to add it to map using the data layer and its `loadGeoJson()` method:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#load_geojson

You can style colors of GeoJSON objects and create info windows. Just read the aforementioned documentation.

I hope this helps!