# How to Find list of latitude and longitude using pincode as input

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-maps-markers

is there any way we can we find list of latitude and longitude using zip/pincode?

```
Input: 560103
Output : 
12.123456, 72.123456
12.123654, 72.366666
....   
....
12.123456, 72.123456
```

on google maps, list of lat-long polygon display would be like below map..
[image]

**Note: Output is just for references, its not correct.**

Comment: Google maps don't always show pincodes of places. So I guess the reverse may also not always be possible

Comment: why would one input result in 3 or more output?

Comment: please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585957/get-latlng-from-zip-code-google-maps-api question if it will help..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing region on google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44570996/drawing-region-on-google-maps)

Answer (score 1):

u have to install pyzipcode from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyzipcode
Later try this code

```
from pyzipcode import ZipCodeDatabase
zcdb = ZipCodeDatabase()
zipcode = zcdb[54115]
print zipcode.zip
print zipcode.city
print zipcode.state
print zipcode.longitude
print zipcode.latitude
print zipcode.timezone
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Google Api](http://maps.googleapis.com)

Check this out

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=110029&sensor=true

This will give you the approx location of pincode 110029

All you have to do is parse the json end extract the coordinates