# Google Maps API Postal Code Boundaries

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've found an answer using Google Maps Marker but since its dead, I hit a dead end.

I was wondering if anyone would have any knowledge on how I would replicate this for a user on my website: https://www.google.ca/maps/place/Toronto,+ON+M4N+3M5/@43.7216028,-79.3771275,16z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89d4cd2e4f1652cd:0xee93f0117ea5797d!8m2!3d43.7215696!4d-79.3768256

I would like to take the users postal code and outline there boundaries. I'm not sure if this a broad question but I need to stick with using Google Maps API in this case.

Comment: you need a data source to provide the boundaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was googles geo coding api: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

It gives the boundaries you need for a neighbourhood which then can be used against the google maps api to plot the area.

Comment: Google Maps Geocoding API only returns lat/lng and bounding box for a given address which obviously is not the same as the boundaries they store for a postal code.

Answer (score 5):

Currently Google Maps JavaScript API doesn't expose any boundaries of geographic features. There is very old feature request in the public issue tracker to add this functionality, however it looks like Google didn't set high priority on this task:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35816953

Feel free to star the public feature request to express your interest and subscribe to further updates from Google.

You can get polygons from other sources and add them to Google maps as additional layers.

The nice workaround to get polygons in GeoJSON format from OpenStreetMap is described in the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40172098/5140781

So, if you download the GeoJSON you will be able to add it to map using the data layer and its `loadGeoJson()` method:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#load_geojson

You can style colors of GeoJSON objects and create info windows. Just read the aforementioned documentation.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

You can't get the boundaries directly from Google Maps API. Best option would be to have geojson files for each postal code and then load the relevant one as a geojson layer in Google Maps.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#load_geojson