# Retrieving local districts from Google Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am creating an android app which will be used in Africa. My app is using Google map to show users the nearest businesses they are looking for. My question is, I want to know the district which the user is based on their GPS location (lat/lang). As you can see the attached image, Google knows the boundaries of the local districts (in this case Somalia). Do Google provide such information? or is there any other way I can do it myself. I searched online but couldn't find any useful information about this. Please help.

[image]

Comment: I'd check OpenStreetMap instead.

Comment: Google doesn't expose boundaries in their APIs, you should get them from other sources. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40172098/5140781

Comment: Thank you guys. I managed to do it by using the [Ray Casting](http://vinsol.com/blog/2016/08/04/ray-casting-algorithm/) algorithm and defined the borders of districts as groups of latitudes and longitudes (in my case I have 7 districts, each group represents a district) then the application checks the user's location in each of these 7 groups and then returns with the group the user location is inside. This may not be the best solution but it works for me.